# XS:Group causes Schema to fail validation

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I have an XML document based on a Schema that uses the xs:group element to bunch elements together.

The result is an entity

where name, address and phone number are defined in a group.

This fails Schema validation in MS (Visual Studio) as well as XERCES (oXygen XML editor)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the XML structure as well as the schema you are using for validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In creating a sample XML to post, I was able to determine that validation was only failing because my element order was incorrect. Whoops!